# Instantiating in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

basically I have made a very simple game that has blocks falling, I have basic C# knowledge but I can't really figure out on my own how I would go about this. Basically I'm dropping 3 blocks one in the middle, left, and right that you have to avoid. I have made an instantiation script that spawns them on each spawn position within 1 to 4 seconds randomly, but sometimes it will accidentally spawn all 3! I just need a check to see if 2 have already spawned on the left and right, then don't spawn one in the middle, and vice versa. Could you guys help me? Thanks! Btw this is my current spawn script.

```
     public GameObject spawn;
     private float spawnTime;

     void Start()
     {  
         spawnTime = Random.Range(1, 5);
         Invoke("Spawn", spawnTime); 
     }

     void Spawn()
     {
         spawnTime = Random.Range(1, 5);
         Instantiate(spawn, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
         Invoke("Spawn", spawnTime);   
     }
```

EDIT:

```
using UnityEngine;
```

public class randomSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{

```
public GameObject spawn;
private float spawnTime = 1;


void Start()
{
    if (GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Cube").Length < 2)
    {
        spawnTime = Random.Range(1, 3);
        Invoke("Spawn", spawnTime);

    }
}


void Spawn()
{
    if (GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Cube").Length < 2)
    {
        spawnTime = Random.Range(1, 3);
        Instantiate(spawn, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        Invoke("Spawn", spawnTime);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Is this script attached to the Blocks that are being spawned?

Comment: @CNuts it was not, but now that I have applied it to each Cube being spawned, it will spawn them on top of each other as they are falling haha.

Comment: I'm going to add a destroyer script to the cubes being spawned themselves and destroy them if there is more than 2 and maybe that will fix it, I will post back.

Comment: That worked actually but I think you method would have been way better, and I figured out why it wasn't working, at one point Unity crashed and it didn't save my tag on my Cube object! hahah! But now actually they only spawn once then never spawn again.

Comment: That's because you need to take the call to `invoke` outside the if statement like in the example I gave in my answer.

Comment: @CNuts oh haha yeah silly me, is there a way with the instantiating that I can only spawn one prefab for each gameobject that has the spawn script? For example, sometimes my game is dropping down 2 blocks on the same area instead of the desired just single one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a tag on your blocks let's say `Block` and then before instantiating one you do `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Block");` which will return an array and then you just verify the length of that array.

```
void Spawn()
{
    if(GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Block").Length < 2){
        Instantiate(spawn, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
    spawnTime = Random.Range(1, 5);
    Invoke("Spawn", spawnTime);   
}
```

You could also have a `static` variable that you increment when spawning a block and decrement when you destroy one.

Comment: Wow that is way more simple than I was trying to imagine it as, thank you for your help!

Comment: Actually I am now running into an error, it is saying GameObject doesn't contain a definition for length. EDIT: I fixed it, it was a simple mistake, I am not familiar with the unity api and made the simplest mistake of my life haha sorry to bother, thanks for the help!

Comment: @enyap Are you sure you're using `FindGameObjectsWithTag` and not `FindWithTag`

Comment: I forgot the "s" I was using FindGameObjectWithTag, but anyways, this script still allows for more than 2 to be spawned, I tried a bunch of different variables and comparisons and for some reason it allows 3 to be spawned, yet if I set it to 0 then it doesn't allow any to be spawned, it doesn't make any sense. I can't figure out what is happening

Comment: @enyap Could you edit your question and show what your script looks like after the changes?